# With jQuery, best way to round off and commify matched elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple (usually 4) elements on a given page that display raw data in a string of digits. I want to round off and commify each one, so that it displays 332,974 instead of 332974.0. I have the right commify function, but I can't get it to match and modify each matched element properly. Here's what I have:

```
function formatScore(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

$('.scoreboard .score p').text(formatScore($(this).text()));


<div class="scoreboard">...
   <div class="score"><p>342352343</p></div>...
   <div class="score"><p>243523432.0</p></div>...
   <div class="score"><p>30980943.3</p></div>...
   <div class="score"><p>78908794.0</p></div>...
</div>
```

Comment: Did you want to implement a round up approach or just truncate any decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down your code:

```
var text = $(this).text();
var formatted = formatScore(text);
$(".scoreboard .score p").text(formatted);
```

Hopefully this shows you that you've done something wrong - if nothing else, you're setting all of your elements to have the same value!

Instead, try:

```
$(".scoreboard .score p").text(function(_,score) {return formatScore(score);});
```

See also the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

Try accounting.js. It works well for my project.

http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/